# Android application RuntimeException in ActivityThread failed to find some source?

Tags: java, android

I need assistance with resolving RuntimeException problem risen by native Android application.
I can not define what causes this exception. Here is stack trace and code. What seems to be an issue here?

```
Thread [<1> main] (Suspended (exception RuntimeException))  
    ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, Intent) line: 1879    
    ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, Intent) line: 1980 
    ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread, ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, Intent) line: 122    
    ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(Message) line: 1146  
    ActivityThread$H(Handler).dispatchMessage(Message) line: 99 
    Looper.loop() line: 137 
    ActivityThread.main(String[]) line: 4340    
    Method.invokeNative(Object, Object[], Class, Class[], Class, int, boolean) line: not available [native method]  
    Method.invoke(Object, Object...) line: 511  
    ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run() line: 784  
    ZygoteInit.main(String[]) line: 551 
    NativeStart.main(String[]) line: not available [native method]
```

Code

```
package com.example;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.example.hellogooglemaps.R;
import com.google.android.maps.MapActivity;
import com.google.android.maps.MapView;

import com.google.android.maps.MapView.LayoutParams;  
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

import com.google.android.maps.GeoPoint;
import com.google.android.maps.MapController;

import java.util.List;

import com.google.android.maps.Overlay;
import com.google.android.maps.MapView.LayoutParams;

import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Point;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

import android.widget.Toast;

public class HellogooglemapsActivity extends MapActivity {
    MapView mapView; 
    MapController mc;
    GeoPoint p,p2;
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.main);

       mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapview);
       LinearLayout zoomLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.zoom);  
       View zoomView = mapView.getZoomControls(); 

       zoomLayout.addView(zoomView, 
           new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
               LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 
               LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)); 
       mapView.displayZoomControls(true);

       mc = mapView.getController();
       String coordinates[] = {"59.3948", "24.662"};
       double lat = Double.parseDouble(coordinates[0]);
       double lng = Double.parseDouble(coordinates[1]);

       p = new GeoPoint(
           (int) (lat * 1E6), 
           (int) (lng * 1E6));

       MapOverlay mapOverlay = new MapOverlay();
       List<Overlay> listOfOverlays = mapView.getOverlays();
       listOfOverlays.clear();
       listOfOverlays.add(mapOverlay); 

       mc.animateTo(p);
       mc.setZoom(14); 
       mapView.invalidate();

   }
    class MapOverlay extends com.google.android.maps.Overlay {
        @Override
        public boolean draw(Canvas canvas, MapView mapView, 
        boolean shadow, long when) 
        {
            super.draw(canvas, mapView, shadow);                   

            //---translate the GeoPoint created in onCreate to screen pixels---
            Point screenPts = new Point();
            mapView.getProjection().toPixels(p, screenPts);

            //---add the marker---
            Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(
                getResources(), R.drawable.map_marker);            
            canvas.drawBitmap(bmp, screenPts.x-15, screenPts.y-32, null);      

            // add a new marker to coords given below
            String coordinates[] = {"59.40", "24.80"};
            double lat = Double.parseDouble(coordinates[0]);
            double lng = Double.parseDouble(coordinates[1]);
            p2 = new GeoPoint( (int) (lat * 1E6), (int) (lng * 1E6));
            Point screenPts2 = new Point();
            mapView.getProjection().toPixels(p2, screenPts2);               
            canvas.drawBitmap(bmp, screenPts2.x-15, screenPts2.y-32, null); 

            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), 
                    p2.getLatitudeE6() / 1E6 + "," + 
                    p2.getLongitudeE6() /1E6 , 
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            return true;
        }
} 
    @Override
    protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }
}
```

AVD : Google API 14

Comment: Is that the entire exception?  I don't see any of the code that you'd pasted in the exception.

Answer (score 1):

The exception stack trace + message is normally printed a bit more verbatim to logcat. The first line of the stack trace indicates that the activity object cannot be instantiated when the system calls Instrumentation.newActivity(ClassLoader, String, Intent). In logcat, you should be able to find something like "Unable to instantiate activity <component>: <message>", where <message> is something you're pretty interested in.

Comment: I don't see this error message, but my test also has no Activity, so I wonder if that's why I'm seeing this crash.